# Xamarin NSTextStorage from NSAttributedString

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I trying to port this line to xamarin

```
let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: self.attributedText!)
```

but I can't find a constructor or static method that takes an NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSTextStorage`'s `attributedString:` initializer is missing on `Xamarin.iOS`.

You can perform an `Append`|`Insert` on your `NSTextStorage` object (which is really appending/inserting on the `NSMutableAttributedString` subclass).

Since your NSTextStorage would be empty as it was just instanced, just use `Append`:

```
var textStorage = new NSTextStorage();
textStorage.Append(someMutableAttributedString);
```

**Note**: This initializer was manually added to the `Xamarin.Mac`'s  `AppKit` framework as a partial class (something in the API generator must not like how it is defined).